# Where to find source code of Linux NTFS driver?

Tags: linux, ntfs, drivers

Brief description :

Linux driver gives us a chance to interface with an NTFS filesystem. Thanks to this driver, we can use built-in Linux commands on an NTFS filesystem.

Ex : ls, chown, chmod, cd, locate, rm, ln  etc.

Question :

Where  can I find this source code ?

Why :

Try to be familiar with NTFS

Comment: Just to be clear, `ls`, `locate` etc. have nothing to do with ntfs itself. These utilities use systemcalls to get their information.

Comment: Beware. The NTFS code with Ubuntu 18.04, 18.10, 19.04, and 19.10 have problems with external USB drives larger than 5TB. When attempting to copy files to/from 6TB or 8TB drives the copying is glacial. At least 10 times slower than when read/writing 4TB drives. Obviously there is a problem-in-scale bug.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the in kernel NTFS driver, your distro may have a kernel source package, which you can install and poke around.  It is usually installed to `/usr/src`

If you used the ntfs-3g driver, the code is here: 
 [NTFS-3G Tarball](http://tuxera.com/opensource/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15.tgz)

Comment: which one is driver for ntfs in /usr/src ?

Comment: I have looked in NTFS-3G tarball, but I could not see implementation of locate. I am looking also source code of locate, ln, rmdir for ntfs.

Comment: @user1423470 `locate` is an external utility, unrelated to NTFS.

Comment: I agree with Chris Down.  I believe that locate, ln, rmdir are not dependedent on a specific FS.  In other words, I believe they are written to work with any file system.

Answer (score 1):

NTFS driver is found inside the **fs/ntfs** folder in the linux kernel source tree.

Find the code here : **http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.5.3/fs/ntfs/**